# Div shifted in IE Compatibility Mode

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, cross-browser

The Close to Play button on the advertisement box is shifted to the right for some reason on IE, when Compatibility mode is checked

Screenshot:

[image]

http://piclair.com/data/2sm0j.jpg

URL: http://www.animefushigi.com/sacred-seven-episode-6/4

Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: I believe the problem may be the margin-left. But without that then it will look correct on other browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I believe the problem may be the margin-left. But without that then it
>   will look correct on other browsers.

Replace `margin-left: 42%` with `margin: auto` :)

This works because: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth

> Block-level, non-replaced elements in normal flow
>
> If both 'margin-left' and 'margin-right' are 'auto', their used values
>   are equal. This horizontally centers the element with respect to the
>   edges of the containing block.

Comment: oh, how about remove margin left and doing margin:auto --- will that work correctly ?

Comment: Yes, that works, and it's much simpler. Oops? I couldn't see the forest for the trees..